# How to change php configuration ? (Xampp)

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-curl

[xampp php config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy7ab.jpg)

Hello sir,
I using xampp.I need to change php configuration.I want "-witch-curl=". This php.ini does not exist either.

Comment: Do not put images of text in questions.  You should just cut-paste the text in here and format it as code (`{}` icon in the editor).  That being said, option "-with-curl" is present in the configure command, which indicates that the module was compiled into your php instance.  This option does not go in to php.ini, it is a build (compilation) configuration directive.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9170226) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).